# Tabularx, tcolorbox and spacing: how to remove the empty line?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, tabularx, tcolorbox

Consider the following example, inspired from the previous post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394392/17200):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,theorems,breakable,most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tcbtab}{O{}m+m}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    titlerule = 0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    middle=0pt,
    colframe = black,
    box align=center,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    boxed title style={
      enhanced,
      colback = black,
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
    },
    listing only,
    title = {\centering\makebox[\linewidth][c]{#2}},%
    #1%
    ]
    #3%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\tcbtab[
    attach boxed title to top={xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm},%
    tabularx={X|p{2cm}}%
]{Title}{%
First column & Second column \\
\hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2
}
\lipsum[1]
\tcbtab[
    attach boxed title to bottom={xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm},%
    tabularx={X|p{2cm}}%
]{Title}{%
First column & Second column \\
\hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2
}
\end{document}
```

There is a one line spacing before or after the table depending on where the title is positioned. How to remove this spacing (while keeping the possibility to put the title at the top or at the bottom of the `tcolorbox`?

[image]

Comment: Remove the `{xshift=..., yshift= ...}` statement

Comment: @ChristianHupfer suggestion does solve the problem. Is this question candidate to be closed as off-topic?

Comment: @Cragfelt: My suggestion does solve the problem, but I had no time to investigate the reason. Keep it open, I'll try to find out

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok that is your call. But I still thinking that question is solved, since the OP was asking just "how to remove the empty line?".

Comment: @Cragfelt: Found a 'solution' or 'explanation'. Looks like a bug to me, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the additional spacing above (or below) the table is that `yshift` does not keep `yshifttext` from being non-zero. `yshifttext` seems to have the value of height of the boxed title. Perhaps this is a bug of `tcolorbox`.

A solution is either to set `yshifttext=0pt` or `yshift*=0mm` .

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,theorems,breakable,most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tcbtab}{O{}m+m}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    titlerule = 0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    middle=0pt,
    colframe = black,
    box align=center,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    boxed title style={
      enhanced,
      colback = black,
      sharp corners,
    },
    %listing only,
    title = {\centering\makebox[\linewidth][c]{#2}},%
    #1%
    ]%
    #3%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\tcbtab[
attach boxed title to top={yshift=0mm,yshifttext=0pt},%
tabularx={X|p{2cm}}%
]{Title}{%
First column  &Second column \\
\hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2
}
\lipsum[1]
\tcbtab[
attach boxed title to bottom={xshift=0mm,yshift*=0mm},%
tabularx={X|p{2cm}}%
]{Title}{%
  First column & Second column \\
  \hline
  Cell 1 & Cell 2 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]