# How to center horizontally a tcolorbox in the page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

I would like to center a `tcolorbox` in the page (or column, etc.) that has a smaller width than `\linewidth`.

Is there a better way to do it than nesting the `tcolorbox` in a `\begin-\end{center}`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
I would like the following box to be centered in the column. Here is a direct way to do it, instead of using \verb+\begin-\end{center}+?
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.75\linewidth]
This is a test.
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A tcolorbox centered and automatically adjusted to the current text size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394381/a-tcolorbox-centered-and-automatically-adjusted-to-the-current-text-size)

Comment: @bmv It seems that the suggestion won't do it (for me box align=center does not yield the expected result).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add option `center`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
I would like the following box to be centered in the column. Here is a direct way to do it, instead of using \verb+\begin-\end{center}+?
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.75\linewidth, center]
This is a test.
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]